# How to sort an Array where I can swap two elements in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, swap

I want to sort below array where I can swap two elements only.

**Example :**

```
NSArray *arr = @[@10, @20, @60, @40, @50, @30];  
// 30 and 60 are swapped
Output: 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60
```

Looking for answers in Objective-C or Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [exchangeObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablearray/1411160-exchangeobject) function below is the right methods.

```
NSArray *arr = @[@10, @20, @60, @40, @50, @30];
    int n = (int)arr.count;

    NSMutableArray *arrm = [arr mutableCopy];

        for (int i = n-1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            // Check if arrm[i] is not in order
            if (arrm[i] < arrm[i-1])
            {
                // Find the other element to be
                // swapped with arr[i]
                int j = i-1;
                while (j>=0 && arrm[i] < arrm[j])
                    j--;

                // Swap the pair
                [arrm exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:j+1];
                break;
            }
        }

    NSLog(@"Given array is :%@",arr);
    NSLog(@"Sorted array is :%@",arrm);
```

Good luck!